# SOLR Terms Component with Analyzer

Tags: solr, analyzer

I've created a field with an Analyzer that is used at index and query phase. However, when I use the Terms Component (`/terms` request handler), the terms defined in the `terms.list` are not processed by the analyzer, so there are a lot of tokens that are not matched because they are not in the way they are indexed.

Is there any way to use the `Terms Component` in a way that the terms in the `terms.list` field are also processed by the analyzer of the `terms.fl` field?

Comment: What issue are you actually trying to solve? If you want to use the analyzer, a regular query would do just that, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MatsLindh I thought so too, but apparently not. When I make a request to `/terms`, the terms included in `terms.list` are not processed by the analyzer, which means that, for example, as the parser has a `LowerCaseFilter`, if I do a request with `terms.list = HELLO, PETER`, it will not find any results, because it does not match with `hello` and `peter` (in lowercase).

Comment: I'm thinking of a regular query - i.e. not using the terms component for querying, and then using faceting to get the indexed terms, but that will give you all terms, not just those that are processed to be a specific term .. so that might not work. What issue are you actually trying to solve? (i.e. why are you doing this?)

Comment: @MatsLindh Yup, that was my first approximation, but then I actually came across the problem of returning all tokens and not just those on the query.
Basically, what I am trying to do is, for a set of tokens, query some individual values of each token, like the document frequency.

Comment: My initial suggestion is to run your search query through the analysis endpoint (which you can see if you open up your developer tools in your browser and go to the network tab and then navigate to "Analysis" for your collection), which will give you the resulting tokens from your query string - then use those tokens with the terms component.

Comment: Yup, that solved my problem. Thanks a lot @MatsLindh.